# Django Stripe account link return_url and refresh_url redirects causes user to be logged out of web application platform

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I'm integrating stripe into my Django web application platform.  When sellers onboard with Stripe Connect, an Account is created for them, and an AccountLink is created with a specified return_url and refresh_url that Stripe uses to redirect back to my web application.  However, when the sellers are redirected back to my web application they are no longer logged into the web application.  Is there a better solution than forcing the user to log back in?

The following are some code snippets:

**views.py**

```
def stripe_on_boarding(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        stripe_sk = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
        stripe.api_key = stripe_sk

        user = request.user
        account = None

        print("I'm logged in as and am onboarding stripe [" + user.first_name + "]")

        if user.stripe_account is None:
            account = stripe.Account.create(type='express')
            user.stripe_account = account.id
            user.save()
            print("Saved User Object!")

        else:
            account = stripe.Account.retrieve(user.stripe_account)

        if account is not None and not account.details_submitted:
            account_links = stripe.AccountLink.create(
                account=account.id,
                refresh_url='http://098c818fbf8a.ngrok.io/marketplace/stripe_on_boarding_refresh',
                return_url='http://098c818fbf8a.ngrok.io/marketplace/seller_return',
                type='account_onboarding',
            )

            return redirect(account_links.url)

        return render(request, 'become_seller_part_1.html', {'msg' : "You've already registered with stripe.", 'is_registered' : True})
    # TODO: render a page if this view was triggered by a method other than GET.
```

Could this be happening because I'm using ngrok to redirect to my localhost?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that it is because I'm using ngrok.  You must use the same URL throughout a session; that is, you can not login as a user on localhost and maintain the session when being redirected to the ngrok URL.

The solution is to use the ngrok URL when logging in as a user.